# calling a multivariable function iteratively with 2d arrays

Tags: python, performance, numpy, iteration

Is there a more efficient way to call a function like this:

```
def func(x,y):
    # do something here
```

when arguments passed are arrays like this?

```
X = np.random.rand(5)
Y = np.random.rand(5,25)
```

I use list comprehension in this form:

```
res = np.array([[func(x,y) for x in X] for y in Y])
```

but was wondering if I could figure out some faster way in numpy, in order to avoid the 'under the hood' loop that happens.

Comment: not really (`np.vectorize` does it, but its not faster, or maybe a very little bit), you should change the function to begin with. To be clear... That is the function should work on all of the array at once if possible, it depends on what the function is here.

Comment: make the function accept an array and iterate through it

Comment: would that be enough to redefine the function in order to accept the arrays as arguments and then iterate (maybe in the similar way as before, i.e. via list comprehension) INSIDE the function? is it faster?

Comment: whether or not you can vectorize the function depends on the function

Comment: Have you tried calling the function as-is with array arguments?  It might work fine without any changes--it depends what kind of operations are performed in the function.

Comment: yes, it needs to be redefined to accept arrays